# Adding Images into Excel Using Excel Package Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have tried the below C# coding :

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test Page");

        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            ws.Row(a * 5).Height = 39.00D;
        }

        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            var picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture(a.ToString(), logo);
            picture.SetPosition(a * 5, 0, 2, 0);
        }
```

I got error saying "**Drawing doesn't support for Excel Package**" because I am using [Excel Package Library](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com)

Any Solution for this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **[EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)** library it may be useful for you, I hope it will satisfy your requirement